# Unable to load next checkout step after editing translate file

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

A few weeks ago I started my own Magento webshop. Because I'm Dutch, I installed and applied the Dutch translation package. After editing the checkout translate file it isn't possible anymore to load step 2 of my checkout page. After clicking on the 'go further' button nothing really happens. I don't even get an error or something. I have refreshed my cache already.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Many many thanks in advance for your reaction.

Dion Hoofwijk

Comment: i also face same problem after bangla convert from front-end (enable developer section).plz response here if get solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, an ajax call is done. Most of the times this issue occurs when there is an error in your ajax call. It could be that the result of the ajax call is an error in your code.